# check if list element contains at least 3 uppercase characters

Tags: python

i am scanning reddit posts by extracting the text from the title and checking if there is a stock ticker contained in the title that would look something like this:

$XXX OR $XXXX

or

XXX OR XXXX

first i get the title then i partition the words into a list

```
title = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/h1").text
title = title.split()
```

output:

```
['Why', '$SAM', 'is', 'the', 'ultimate', 'lotto']
```

then i check if there is a $ contained in any of the list elements

```
likely_ticker = [string for string in title if "$" in string]
```

output:

```
['$SAM']
```

but if there is no $ i want to the code to be able to recognize any list element that contains atleast 3 uppercase characters

how?

Comment: isupper(), but note that you will have to iterate through each word to count the uppercase and whether it is uppercase or not.

Comment: Try using *regular expressions* `^\$?[A-Z]{3,4}$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

additionally use `isupper` and `len` function on string with `and` operator. see below:

```
title = ['Why', '$SAM', 'is', 'the', 'ultimate', 'LET', '$DEFR', 'DEFR', 'lotto']

print([item for item in title if '$' in item or (len(item) > 2 and item.isupper())])
```

Output:

```
['$SAM', 'LET', '$DEFR', 'DEFR']
```

Comment: The question is `check if list element contains at least 3 uppercase characters` and after a test I see the code did not work for this example: `title = ['theURL']`

Comment: because the example given by OP is that, they all should be in continuation:
like.. XXX OR XXXX, see in question.

Answer (score 1):

To count the number of uppercase characters in a string you can use:

```
sum(ch.isupper() for ch in string)
```

So, to filter list items by those with at least 3:

```
results = [item for item in seq if sum(ch.isupper() for ch in item) >= 3]
```

Comment: This should be the answer. Since it's the only answer satisfy the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with regular expressions. This checks for three consecutive uppercase characters:

```py
import re

likely_ticker = [string for string in title if re.search(r'[A-Z]{3}', string)]

# For title = ['AAA' , 'AAAAA', 'aaaaaa', 'AA AA']
# returns:  ['AAA', 'AAAAA']
```

Comment: The question is `check if list element contains at least 3 uppercase characters` and after a test I see the code did not work for this example: `title = ['theURL']`

Comment: Yes, @MSH. I should have used `re.search` instead of `re.match`.